# Can anyone explain some unfamiliar terms in PS Vita for a beginner gamer like me?

Tags: controllers, ps-vita

So, I'm a grown-ass adult, but I've never played much game before other than on my phone. Since I'm on vacation and have a lot free time to spare, I'm looking to buy a PS Vita for gaming. However, I don't really know anything much about that stuff.

I know there are PS Vita and Vita Slim. But when I browsed a quite popular website in my country looking to buy 2nd hand PS Vita, I saw there were ads selling PS Vita 2000 from Japan for $160. What does the 2000 mean? Should I buy one that says it's from Japan? Is there another way to say psvista slim 3.68 jailbroken for $165. What does 3.68 mean? And the dumbest question, what does Jailbreak really mean? I saw that word all the time but never really understood it.

**TLDR;** What do the following terms mean in regards to PS Vita/Vita Slim:

- 2000
- 3.68
- Jailbroken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 2000

This refers to both the model of the Vita as well as where it was released. The 2000 model you were looking at was the Vita PCH-2000. [This Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/vita/comments/2eqzhw/ps_vita_pch2000_vs_2006/) explains that the 2000 model is the one released in Japan, compared to the 2001 for the US, the 2003 for the UK, and the 2006 for general Asia. So they will be the same feature wise, just from separate regions.

## Jailbreak

This refers to the process of using an exploit in a device to gain higher access/privileges than one would normally be allowed on that given device. This generally allows a user to modify the operating system or install applications in ways that aren't generally allowed by the operating system.

**Note: There are generally risks associated with jailbreaking a device and it is extremely important to look into these risks before going forward with the process on any device.**

## 3.68

This refers to the version of the firmware that the Vita is running. When someone says that they have a "Vita Slim 3.68" it means that it's running firmware version 3.68. This version is significant for some as it represents the final version where the popular Jailbreak [h-encore](https://github.com/TheOfficialFloW/h-encore) can run.

---

## In Conclusion

Whether or not you want to buy a Japanese Vita is up to you, [this GameFAQs thread](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/620272-playstation-vita/76785607) explains what some of the differences are between the Japanese and American Vitas.

When someone says they're selling a Vita Slim 3.68 Jailbroken, it most likely means that they're using h-encore or a similar program to install patches alongside the operating system that will come with the system when purchased.

Comment: Wow~ thanks a lot!! You just explained everything!!

Comment: No problem! Let me know if you have any questions about what I mentioned.